# change button color on-click and remains same for rest of the time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, onclick

here is the thing I'm trying to make my button change colour so that user can see that he already clicked on the button. and even if he refreshes the page, the button will remain in the same colour as it was after he clicks first. the reason is that im showing a lot of buttons on one page. here is my button code.

```html
<button id="ikk" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="UZqTjJnRVdGQjQ">Procced </button>
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried? It will be easier to help

Comment: Please add your codes(with your js and html or php) to describe your problem with output now you get

Comment: sorry im new i added the code, thanks for the quick help.

Comment: You should use 'cookies' if you want your code to "remember" that updated status of an event (such as: the user clicked the button). Then check if that cookie exists - and if so, use a different color for the button.

Comment: Do you want to retain the newly applied colour if page reloads?

Comment: i have tried this javascript but it is not working with this button

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" ).click(function() {
    $( ".btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" ).css('background', 'green');
  });
});

Comment: @Oceanoffiles.com view my answer.

Comment: @Oceanoffiles.com view my (edited) answer, it makes what you want.

Comment: worrrrrrrrrrrrkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkeeeeeeeeeeed

Comment: worked, love you guys thanks for the help, i really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Oceanoffiles.com, you might want to accept the answer that worked for you as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this works for me http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/6/

```js
$( "#myBtn" ).click(function() {

$(this).addClass('myclass');

localStorage.setItem('clicked', '1');

});



if(localStorage.getItem("clicked") != null){

$("#myBtn").addClass('myclass');


}
```

```css
.myclass{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="IeUtIMnV0V1JpQlU">Procced</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/

You can make a use of `localStorage` and `jQuery` to achieve this.

**simple code:**

```
///APPLY A CSS TO THE BUTTON WHEN ITS CLICKED//////

    $( "#someid" ).click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('myclass');

    localStorage.setItem('clicked', '1');

    });



    ////YOU MIGHT WANT TO PUT THIS IN A DOCUMENT READY FUNCTION////

    if(localStorage.getItem("clicked") != null){

    $("#someid").addClass('myclass');


    }
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments below, you already have some CSS styling on your button. so to make sure that the new CSS/colour is applied to your button when its clicked, all you have to do is this:

```
.myclass{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

Take a note of:

```
 !important;
```

**Second Edit:**

The code in the last jsfiddle you've provided works fine if you make sure to change the button's ID:

Basically, your button's ID is `myBtn` but you are not using that ID in the jQuery code. so either change that ID to the same ID that is used in the jQuery code or simply change the ID that is used in the jQuery code to `myBtn`.

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/6/

Comment: I prefer sessionStorage instead localStorage

Comment: it works perfectly on jsfiddle.net but not on the website. can you please explain to me in detail which code should I put where. thanks

Comment: well, it works on website but not with my existing button, i created new button and it works very well as expected. could it be the reason that the button already have  "style" in it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/2/ , yes that is the case here. please give me some advice

Comment: @Oceanoffiles.com just add an !important to the CSS style like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/3/

Comment: @Pandiarajan, LocalStorage is slightly more long lasting than the sessionStorage. Although, they both can easily be deleted/removed by the users. so Not permanent.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/4/ , bro this is the full button code please give it a look I really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

This works to change the color and remember it, even if you refresh with F5.

```
<button id="ikk" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" onclick="btnColorChange(0);" data-uid="UZqTjJnRVdGQjQ">Procced </button>

<script>
    btnColorChange(1);

    function btnColorChange(start)
    {
        if (start)
        {   
            index=document.cookie.search("btnColor");

            if (index != -1)
                btnColor=document.cookie.substr(index+9);
            else
                btnColor="#ef332d";
        }
        else
            btnColor='green';

        btnId = document.getElementById("ikk");
        btnId.style["background"] = btnColor;

        document.cookie = "btnColor="+btnColor;
    }
</script>
```

If you want, you can put in some logic to change with every click to the next color. For this you have to change the line *btnColor='green'* with your favorit code.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on how permanent you want the clicked colour to be.
Considering your case you could use `cookies`, `cache` or `localStorage` but the data in any of these can be deleted by the user or if the user uses some other system to log in and click on the button the clicked colour may not be available, therefore the best solution for this problem could be to store it in `database` so each time the user logs in, the clicked button's colour would be changed permanently.

If you still want to do it with the localStorage, here's a link to help you along:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage