# change button color on-click for multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, onclick

the previous question answer is working,[click here to see.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947978/change-button-color-on-click-and-remains-same-for-rest-of-the-time) but only for the single button not for multiple buttons for reference look here http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/9/

```js
$( "#myBtn" ).click(function() {

$(this).addClass('myclass');

localStorage.setItem('clicked', '1');

});



if(localStorage.getItem("clicked") != null){

$("#myBtn").addClass('myclass');


}
```

```css
.myclass{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="IeUtIMnV0V1JpQlU">Procced</button>

<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="khjdvhbjdhjbvjkbs">Procced 2</button>

<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="hdfhkdsvkhvs">Procced 3</button>

so-on
```

Comment: Don't create multiple elements with same id. Attach the event handler to class rather than id.

Comment: Also don't link to an older question and just put the information that is needed in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple elements are not allowed to have same ID. So instead of selecting the buttons using their ID `#myBtn`, you should select them using the class `.myBtn`.

Also, for `localStorage` you could store the ID of clicked buttons in an array.

### HTML

```
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="sdhjbaskjhnbsdvkjnd">Procced</button>

<button id="myBtn1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="hbsddjhbsdjbhsd">Procced 2</button>

<button id="myBtn2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="kjfkjbsdkbjsdvbjk">Procced 3</button>


so-on
```

### JS

```
$(".myBtn").click(function() {

  $(this).addClass('myclass');

    var itemsStr = localStorage.getItem('clicked');
  var items = [];
  if(itemsStr) {
     items = JSON.parse(itemsStr);
  }
    items.push($(this).attr("id"));
  localStorage.setItem('clicked',JSON.stringify(items));

});

if (localStorage.getItem("clicked") != null) {
  var itemsStr = localStorage.getItem('clicked');
  var items = [];
  if(itemsStr) {
     items = JSON.parse(itemsStr);
  }

  items.forEach(function(id) {
    $("#" + id).addClass("myclass");
  });
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/11/

I've a couple of other suggestions:

- Avoid setting inline styles: `style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;"`. Instead you can create a CSS class having these styles and then set it to the buttons.
- Avoid using `!important` whenever possible. It is generally considered a bad practice.

Comment: I Would really appreciate if you could perform it here http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/9/ I'm having trouble in executing the code. thanks

Comment: @oceanoffilescom Yup, I just realized. I add the link to the updated fiddle.

Comment: please be advice on the website all the button are with the same id="mybtn", because it is required to execute some scripts, only the data-uid="kjfkjbsdkbjsdvbjk" is different for the buttons. please, I'm in a desperate need of help.

Comment: @oceanoffilescom Is this how you want it: http://jsfiddle.net/wmy8vucb/13/? You can get the `data-uid` using `$(this).attr('data-uid')` while handling click event, and find the button using `$("button[data-uid='uid']")` while setting its class on initial page load.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the jquery link

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

at the bottom of the page and the jquery script after the jquery link.

```html
<button class="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="IeUtIMnV0V1JpQlU">Procced</button>

<button class="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="khjdvhbjdhjbvjkbs">Procced 2</button>

<button class="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="hdfhkdsvkhvs">Procced 3</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".myBtn").click(function() {

        $(this).addClass('myclass');
        localStorage.setItem('clicked', '1');

    });



    if(localStorage.getItem("clicked") != null){

        $(".myBtn").addClass('myclass');


    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The import location of jQuery is not the actual problem here.

Comment: In this code, I changed the id to class and the # to .

Comment: Actually you can't specify the class twice on same element.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your fiddle check the following might be helpful to you.

```js
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
var x=$(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();

if(x=='myclass')
{
$(this).removeClass('myclass');
}
else
{
$(this).addClass('myclass');
}

});
```

```css
.myclass{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="sdhjbaskjhnbsdvkjnd">Procced</button>

<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="hbsddjhbsdjbhsd">Procced 2</button>

<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-default btn-lg myBtn" style="background: #ef332d; color: #fff;" type="button" data-uid="kjfkjbsdkbjsdvbjk">Procced 3</button>


so-on
```

Comment: I appreciate what have you done, but I need to store the click on localStorage to make a record of the click so the user can see which button has been already clicked even if the user refreshes the page. almost everything is working only the issue is that every button on the website share same id=myBtn and so on. Only the data-uid="sdhjkdsh"  is different in buttons, so to overcome this click must be saved on data-uid=''sdhjkdsh'' to determine that only one or two buttons are clicked on a page.